# Realex API integration with DCC not showing pay in currency popup

Tags: php, curl, realex-payments-api

I am using Realex API integration with DCC and below is my code:

MD5 hash creation:

```
$tmp = "$timestamp.$merchantid.$orderid.$amountinCents.$currency.$cardnumber";
$md5hash = md5($tmp);
$tmp = "$md5hash.$secret";
$md5hash = md5($tmp);
```

DCC request xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<request type='dccrate' timestamp='$timestamp'>
    <merchantid>$merchantid</merchantid>
    <account>$account</account>
    <orderid>$orderid</orderid>
    <amount currency='$currency'>$amountinCents</amount>
    <card> 
        <number>$cardnumber</number>
        <expdate>$expdate</expdate>
        <type>$cardtype</type> 
        <chname>$cardname</chname>
        <cvn> 
            <number>$cvvno</number> 
            <presind>1</presind> 
        </cvn>
    </card> 
    <dccinfo>
        <ccp>fexco</ccp>
        <type>1</type>
        <ratetype>S</ratetype>
    </dccinfo>
    <autosettle flag='1'/>
    <md5hash>$md5hash</md5hash>
    <tssinfo>
        <address type=\"billing\">
            <country>ie</country>
        </address>
    </tssinfo>
</request>
```

Auth request xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<request type='auth' timestamp='".$timestamp."'>
    <merchantid>".$merchantid."</merchantid>
    <account>".$account."</account>
    <orderid>".$orderid."</orderid>
    <amount currency='".$currency."'>".$amountinCents."</amount>
    <card>
        <number>".$cardnumber."</number>
        <expdate>".$expdate."</expdate>
        <chname>".$cardname."</chname>
            <type>$cardtype</type> 
        <cvn>
            <number>".$cvvno."</number>
            <presind>1</presind>
        </cvn>
    </card>
    <autosettle flag='1' />
    <md5hash>".$md5hash."</md5hash>
    <dccinfo>
        <ccp>fexco</ccp>
        <type>1</type>
        <rate>".$authrate."</rate>
        <ratetype>S</ratetype>
        <amount currency='".$curr."'>".$amountDcc."</amount>
    </dccinfo>
</request>
```

And sending both xml to "https://epage.payandshop.com/epage-remote.cgi" one after another using curl, The payment process works fine.
But it not showing any popup window for customer to select currency to be charge.

I am looking for this window
[image]

here is sample form for [checking](https://www.dan-dooley.ie/payment2.php)

Can you please advice why it is not showing or do I need to make any changes?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question. Firstly, as I mentioned in the answer to your previous question, we highly recommend you use SHA1 instead of MD5 for the transaction hash.

Also, that URL: https://epage.payandshop.com/epage-remote.cgi, is a legacy one, the new ones are:

Live URL - https://api.realexpayments.com/epage-remote.cgi

Sandbox URL - https://api.sandbox.realexpayments.com/epage-remote.cgi

Can I ask what developer documentation you are referring to? I highly recommend you follow the guides as per the latest Realex Developer Hub. (If there is an issue with the Hub, let me know).

Finally, because you are using DCC through our API, the window / page you are describing must be generated by your application, using the values returned in from the DCC Rate lookup request. This it outlined in Step 2 here, along with a PHP example: https://developer.realexpayments.com/#!/integration-api/dcc/php/html_js

Is there a particular reason you are not using our Hosted Payment Page (HPP) to process the transaction? It handles the display of the rate choice to the customer for you. You'll also benefit from reducing your application's PCI scope. See here: https://developer.realexpayments.com/#!/hpp/dcc

Best,

Seán

**Realex Payments**